# Map value from array to different array type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Im trying to add to an array of object list of objects with key value (typescript)

Hardcoded value

```
const Runtimes: QuickPickItem[] = [{
    label: '$(package-dependents-16) Merge Branch',
    description: '$(git-commit) 1 commit',
    detail: '$(diff-added) 3 $(diff-modified) 2'
},

{
    label: '$(package-dependents-16) commit Branch',
    description: '$(git-commit) 2 commit',
    detail: '$(diff-added) 3 $(diff-modified) 2'
},

];
```

When I do it like this it works!

```
const pick = await input.showQuickPick({
            title,
            step: 1,
            totalSteps: 2,
            placeholder: 'Choose runtime',
            items: Runtimes,
            activeItem: typeof state.resourceGroup !== 'string' ? state.resourceGroup : undefined,
        })
```

Now I’ve array of objects which I want to put inside the Runtime

res.Runtime.data =

```
Array(2) [Object, Object]


Object {id: "14", name: "event1”, description: "delete order event", …}


Object {id: "89", name: "event2", description: "create order event", …}
```

I want to use the name and description.

I want that this **res.Runtime.data = Runtimes  (name & description)**

I tried to create an interface

```
  interface myObj {
        name: string;
        description: string;
    }
```

But still I see one entry, any idea?

**At the end** `runtime` should look like

```
const Runtimes: QuickPickItem[] = [{
        label: 'event1',
        description: 'delete order event'

    },

    {
        label: 'event2',
        description: 'create order event'
    },

    ];
```

I need it to be array of object with `label` and `description`

currently I've tried with

```
const Runtimes: [] = res.Runtime.data .map(((item: { name: string; description: string }) => (item.name, item.description));
```

But I get **just the name** and not an object with **name and description**

Comment: what do you mean `But still I see one entry` where and how do you try render/access the properties?

Comment: @johnSmith - for example it will put only `["event1",`"event2"] and I need it to be like the in the question `[{
        label: 'event1',
        description: 'delete order event'

    },

    {
        label: 'event2',
        description: 'create order event'
    },

    ];` array of object and not array of string values

Comment: @johnSmith - does it answer your question?

Comment: Your map function looks wrong. It should probably be something like `res.Runtime.data.map((item: any) => ({ name: item.name, description: item.description}))`